# I can't set Properly the size of each element on my Java Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, size

```
package View;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.synth.ColorType;
import modulo.PatenteTypes;

import java.awt.*;

public class FrameLogin extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     Color Arancione = new Color(255, 150, 0);

    public FrameLogin(String ArrayClienti[] ){
        this.setTitle("BiKar Prenotazioni");
        this.setSize(new Dimension(1000,600));
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setForeground(Color.black);
        
        JPanel Pannello = new JPanel();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Pannello.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Pannello.setBackground(Color.black);
        Pannello.setForeground(Color.orange);
        this.add(Pannello);
        
        
        JComboBox TipoCliente = new JComboBox(ArrayClienti);
        TipoCliente.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,250));
        TipoCliente.setMaximumSize(TipoCliente.getPreferredSize());
        TipoCliente.setSize(200, TipoCliente.getPreferredSize().height);
        JTextField Nome = new JTextField();
        JTextField Cognome = new JTextField();
        JTextField ID = new JTextField();
        JTextField Eta = new JTextField();
        JComboBox<PatenteTypes> TipoPatente= new JComboBox<PatenteTypes>(PatenteTypes.values());
        
        
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Pannello.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setForeground(Color.black);
        this.add(Pannello);
        this.add(Nome);
        this.add(Cognome);
        this.add(ID,BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(Eta, BorderLayout.EAST);
        this.add(TipoPatente,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(TipoCliente,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        TipoCliente.setBackground(Arancione);
        TipoCliente.setForeground(Arancione);
        Nome.setBackground(Arancione);
        Nome.setForeground(Arancione);
        Cognome.setBackground(Arancione);
        Cognome.setForeground(Arancione);
        ID.setBackground(Arancione);
        ID.setForeground(Arancione);
        Eta.setBackground(Arancione);
        Eta.setForeground(Arancione);
        TipoPatente.setBackground(Arancione);
        TipoPatente.setForeground(Arancione);
        
        
        this.setVisible(true);
        Pannello.setVisible(true);
        TipoCliente.setVisible(true);
        ID.setVisible(true);
        Eta.setVisible(true);
        TipoPatente.setVisible(true);
        Nome.setVisible(false);
        Cognome.setVisible(false);
        
        }
 }
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see in the image the output are 2 very big ComboBox and no TextAreas at all.

I should have gotten 2 small ComboBox. one at the north, the other at the center, and 2 text ares at sides of the combobox at the center. thanks for your help.

I would like to be able to set their dimensione and their position ( I don't want this to be resizable).

also at the border you can see 2 orange lines. I think those where supposed to be the text areas, but all of the space was taken by the JComboBox

Comment: 1) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. 2) When you create a JTextField use something like `new JTextField(10)` to specify the number of characters to display so the component can determine its preferred size. 3) Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). You can nest panels with different layout manager to achieve your desire layout. We can't make a specific suggestion since we don't know what you want. Showing a picture of the "wrong" layout doesn't tell us what you really want.

Comment: Thanks you very much. problema solved now

Comment: Di niente.  ;o)  / You're welcome.

Comment: @Lynx242 *"Use `.setPreferredSize(new Dimension( <VALUE>, <VALUE>));` with all components."* Until you realise how counter-productive that advice is, please stop offering advice on cross-platform GUI development.